# chef recipe to update a value in properties file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a log.properties file with the below content

```
LogFilePathKnown=true
LogFileSizeBytes=10000000
LogFileCount=1
LogFileAppend=true
```

I want to update LogFileAppend=false. How can I do this using a chef recipe. Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1):

You must use a cookbook `template`. To do that you have to create a `erb` file in `templates/default/` from your cookbook root dir. You can organize the template file in different ways depending on your needs and wishes. Check [chef template documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) to see details, examples,.. about its use.

Comment: I created a template log.properties under templates\default Added the below in the recipe template "Updating log properties file: #{log_prop_path}" do
  path  log_prop_path
  source "log.properties"  #located in template/default
  owner user
  group group
  mode 0644
end
But the above throws an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add the error output, and the new code, to the question.  It's near impossible to read code in the comments section of SO.

Comment: @User3 I don't understand very well how you have tried to implement it. Please update your question with your code so we can try to help more precisely.